# Dell Optiplex 9020 and 2560x1440 Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, dell-optiplex

I am buying a [Dell Optiplex 9020](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/optiplex-9020-desktop/pd)  with this GPU:

```
    AMD Radeon™ HD 8570, 1GB DDR3, FH, 1 DP 1 DVI
```

Will this support the native resolution of 2560x1440 via its DVI port?  If not, will I be able to use a `DP to DVI` converter?

I have 2 `2560x1440` monitors that I hope to connect both but they lack DP or HDMI. They only have DVI-D.

I realize that the Dell GPU that I have is low end, so that's why I was concerned about the GPU's support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the specs for the [ATI / AMD 8570 are:](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/8000/Pages/8570.aspx#2)

> - DisplayPort 1.2
>
>   - Max resolution: 4096x2160 @ 60
>       Hz per display
>   - Multi-Stream
>   - 21.6 Gbps
>       bandwidth (HBR2)
>   - High bit-rate audio
>   - Quad
>       HD/4K/UHDTV display support
>   - 1080p60 Stereoscopic 3D (Frame
>       Sequential Format)
> - HDMI® (With 4K, 3D,
>     x.v.Color™ and Deep Color)
>
>   - Max resolution: 4096x2160 @ 30
>       Hz
>   - 1080p30 Stereoscopic 3D (Packed Frame Format)
>   - Quad HD/4K/UHDTV video display support
> - Dual-link DVI with HDCP
>
>   - Max resolution: 2560x1600
> - VGA
>
>   - Max resolution: 2048x1536

Comment: This is not accurate - the DVI port on the card in this machine will not drive a monitor at 2560x1440, as numerous folks have discovered to  their displeasure. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell (after spending hours trying), the DVI port on the Radeon card in the OptiPlex 9020 does not support 2560x1440. Numerous others have had similar issues.

Fortunately there is a simple solution:

The DisplayPort port on the card works just fine. I have one connected via male-male DisplayPort cable to a Dell U2713HM right in front of me, and it is running 2560x1440.

(The onboard chipset also will drive the monitor at this resolution via DisplayPort, although so far I am unsuccessful at running in a 2+ monitor configuration.)

Answer (score 0):

I have an AMD Radeon HD 8570 in my Dell Optiplex 9020.

I just picked up an HP ZR2740w display (2560 x 1440).

The Radeon HD 8570 does not appear to support this resolution despite the fact that the specs claim it supports a max resolution of 2560x1600.
Specs can be seen at:

http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/8000/Pages/8570.aspx#2

I switched some monitors around and found that the HD 8570 does support 1920 x 1200.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but I am not sure how your experience makes this an answer to the OP question.  Unless you can establish yourself as an expert or provide much more detail about what was done, there could be many reasons why you had this problem besides that the specs are wrong.  Perhaps you should post your own question and someone will be able to provide you a better solution?

Comment: @user293122 is inaccurate here - see my answer below.